# No prediction results in response from Google ML Engine online prediction request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-ml

I've got a model set up and running on Google ML Engine, which I can use **successfully** from my personal computer. Now I'm trying to set up Firebase Cloud Functions to make calls to my ML Engine model. I'm really close (I think) but I'm hitting a wall now.

My prediction requests are being received by ML Engine, but I am not getting the prediction results in the callback function.

`results.predictions` is always null, and when I stringified `results` I am seeing this:

[image: Firebase Cloud Functions console]

and Stackdriver shows the request being successfully sent:

[image: Stackdriver logs]

You can also see on the ML Engine Models dashboard, that the `Last use time` **does** reflect when I am calling the cloud function.

[image: My model is being called]

But I can't figure out why I'm not getting the prediction results back from ML Engine.

This is what I have been following as a guide for setting up my Cloud Functions: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-functions-helpdesk/blob/master/functions/index.js

This is my cloud function currently, it is passed the base64 encoded image data through `data.imageData`, and I have verified that it is a valid image encoding by copying the output and running the prediction request from my PC.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

exports.analyzeDetection = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (data.imageData) {
        // Auth
        google.auth.getApplicationDefault((err, authClient) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("getApplicationDefault err " + err);
                return {
                    prediction: "error"
                }
            }

            //[START ml_engine_auth]
            if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
                // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#mlv1
                authClient = authClient.createScoped(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']);
            }

            //Create authenticated ml engine client
            var ml = google.ml({
                version: 'v1',
                auth: authClient
            });
            //[END ml_engine_auth]

            // Prediction
            ml.projects.predict({
                name: `projects/my_project_name/models/my_model_name`,
                resource: {
                    instances: [{"b64": data.imageData}]
                }
            }, (err, result) => {

                // The problem is that result is always null

                if (err){
                    console.error('ERROR ', err);
                    return {
                        prediction: "error"
                    }
                }
                return {
                    prediction: "add this after the prediction requests are working"//result.predictions[0].predicted
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Note: I have obfuscated `my_project_name` and `my_model_name`, that is not what they actually say.

I have also tried multiple different variations of prediction parameters, such as:

```
name: 'projects/my_project_name/models/my_model_name',
resource: {
    instances: [{"image_bytes": {"b64": data.imageData}, "key": "0"}]
}
```

and

```
name: 'projects/my_project_name/models/my_model_name',
resource: {
    name: 'projects/my_project_name/models/my_model_name',
    instances: [{"b64": data.imageData}]
}
```

but they all seem to perform the same.

Any ideas on why I'm not getting the prediction results back from the request? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging, trial, error, etc.. I've determined that the prediction results are stored in `results.data` and not in `results`. For example, I can view my scores in `result.data.predictions[0].scores` and the prediction in `result.data.predictions[0].prediction`. It seems that I was originally tricked by the output limit of the Cloud Functions console, where the `data` property was being truncated so I couldn't see the prediction results.